# TypeError while using 'statsmodels' ExponentialSmoothing to fit triple exponential smoothing

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting

I am new to

> Statsmodels (0.12.0) in python

trying to fit an Exponential Smoothing model to a monthly ts data,  passing the below command in Jupyter NB:

```
hw = ExponentialSmoothing(data0,
                          trend='mul',
                          damped_trend=False,
                          seasonal='add',
                          seasonal_periods=12,
                          initialization_method="estimated",
                          use_boxcox=False).fit()
```

however, getting this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'trend'
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this?
[ref.:error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu1XU.png)

Comment: Have you tried 0.12.1, which was just released?  I think this might have been fixed.

Comment: no not yet, I will try it now though. Thanks for pointing that out. However, I am no longer receiving this error, may be writing a fresh notebook fixed the problem. Not sure!